# Collapse navigate me to new page

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

My problem is that the collapse form doesn't working. I update my application to Angular 4 from angular 2 and I think that is cause the problem.

If I click to collapsible item it navigate me to the new page with the data.parent_id attributes. I want that if I click to the header and the "collapsible" content will be displayed.

Im not sure that the links on the index.html works well, but I try everything what I can.

*( i have app.module.ts and sub module called dashboard module what is render this component )*

document.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
<div *ngFor="let data of data.data">
  <div class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{data.parent_id}}">ID:{{data.parent_id}} SUBJECT:{{data.subject}}</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="#{{data.parent_id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="panel-body">Id: {{data.parent_id}}</div>
      </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

index.html

```
  <head>
     <title>myproject</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->

    <!-- Popper.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>

  <!-- Display the application -->
  <body>
    <base href="/">
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: just a heads up, you should specify the base-href in the `<head></head>` tag, not in the body

Comment: You should include the Bootstrap 4 JavaScript after jQuery and PopperJS. Also you seem to have a bunch of jQuery versions. Only use one version if possible.